# Exclude open-bounty questions in review audits

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

Review audits that have open bounties on them should be removed.

The fact of the matter is review audits *aren't* perfect, and every once in a while a review audit shows a bad question as a good one. This has been discussed and concluded on meta, and is an inevitable fact.

The problem lays in the resolution; I could care less if I fail a faulty audit. However, **I can't actually flag it for closure** due to the open bounty, making the whole system not only detrimental, but incredibly annoying.

So please, spare a *little* sanity left over from the close vote review and keep bountied questions out of review audits.

Comment: Let's hope the "dispute"-button comes soon. Which is another change preserving sanity.

Comment: @Deduplicator Is that something in the works?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188790 And I haven't heard anything about it for some time, so I don't know.

Comment: @Deduplicator That was posted by a mod.  I don't think the SE dev team has officially committed to the idea.

Comment: It's obvious they are audits because you can't vote to close the question with the bounty, so they can't be real queue items.

Comment: I'm hoping this comment bumps this to the front page, at least for activity, because this has become even more of a problem recently.

Comment: I think it shouldn't even consider questions which once had a bounty because these questions appear to be more likely to get upvotes without actually deserving it, causing them to appear as "high quality" for audits even though they aren't - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323360/failed-fp-audit-due-to-downvote-is-my-mental-rule-for-downvoting-wrong

Comment: According to Shog: `FYI, bountied questions are already excluded from use as audits in the Close, Reopen and Triage queues. Should probably just do that everywhere. – Shog9♦ Jul 31 '15 at 17:31` [link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300560/should-i-be-concerned-about-featured-questions-inflating-votes#comment227630_300560). Considering the difference in dates between this Q and his comment, that may be an 'update'. Not sure, but still helpful information.

Comment: Thanks for the info @CubeJockey :)