# I am got blocked from review and I think it is incorrect, what to do now?

Tags: discussion, comments, disputed-review-audits

I was reviewed a question and the result is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9138103). I just left a comment. But it said that I reviewed it wrongly and banned me for one month!

1. Should always a comment be negative?

   - If yes, then there is a comment in the question and it is positive.
   - If no, then why system is designed as the comment is an alternative of down-vote?
2. I found nothing to do with programming in the question. So, what should be the review and why?

#### Note:

I need moderators attention as I got blocked for one month. If you want to close this question as a duplicate of this question, then please, tell me **where the answer of the last question?**.

Comment: Haven't you asked the exact same question a while ago? Oh, I see, you have deleted it. You should have edited it to clarify it instead.

Comment: You were banned because you have failed to many audits.  if the question had nothing to do with programming then you should have chosen an action to get rid of it.  commenting does not get rid of bad material

Comment: Should we close it again against: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because, it is written *"This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Listen, the "duplicate of" question is too old, but it is not implemented yet. So, my another question is also logical.

Comment: Related - There is a [feature request to exclude bounties from audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278398/exclude-open-bounty-questions-in-review-audits).

Answer (score 14):

There are a few things at work here. First, the audit failure. Failing an audit as a result of commenting is a [known issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment) that has been discussed before.

Second, the question itself is probably a bad audit case because of the fact that it received an extreme amount of upvotes as a result of having a bounty on it. This is something [I've expressed concern about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300560/should-i-be-concerned-about-featured-questions-inflating-votes). In fact, 17 of the 21 upvotes for that question came entirely as a result of the exposure it got for having a bounty. For a 50-point bounty, that's an 85-point reputation return. Not a bad investment.

Will I lift your ban as a result of this problematic audit? Probably not. A one-month ban from review doesn't come from a single failed audit. In your case, you failed these two audits in rapid succession, leading to a 2-day, then 7-day ban:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8978780
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9015452

Looking at others, I have concerns that you might not understand what is and is not appropriate in triage, so I'm not going to overturn this ban. While this was a bad audit, I think you might need a little time away to examine some of your recent reviews.

Comment: The first one was just a miss-click, and I am sorry for that. But think, I was banned for those issues, now, why Am I got banned? for system issue. Now I am very sincere about reviewing. You should see my recent reviews.

Comment: @manetsus you got a 2 day ban, then fresh out of it (9 hours later, but yeah) you get another one for a week (so out of it on august 9). 3 days later you get another one? in a little bit over 2 weeks, you've had 9 days being banned, and got banned 3 times.... It seems unlikely you REALLY get it yet :S

Comment: I need no explanation, just answer my question. thanks. @Patrice

Comment: @manetsus well you got banned because in 5 days of reviewing you failed  3 (likely more) reviews. if what we can see doesn't inspire trust... why would the automated system trust you more?

Comment: lol, just read your comment again and try to control you from laughing!! @Patrice

Comment: @manetsus what? you ask why you got banned, I tell you in a total of 5 days of reviewing you made MINIMUM 3 bad calls... so no, you maybe should NOT review, so the ban is appropriate. I fail to see what's funny there. Anyway, You don't seem to REALLY want to know what's wrong here, so enjoy, I'm out!

Comment: What is wrong with this review, just tell me that first. @Patrice

Comment: If nothing wrong with this review, why should I be banned causing this? I got the punishments for those bad calls, remember it. @Patrice

Comment: You messed up multiple reviews, and got justly review-banned for a while - move on.