# Should we allow questions with an active bounty in the triage queue

Tags: discussion, bounty, triage

I was going through the triage queue and got [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9165338) of [ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘multiset’ with no type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882187/iso-c-forbids-declaration-of-multiset-with-no-type).  Looking at the question there is no MCVE and the code is provided only as a link.  I picked unsalvageable and picked the lacks MCVE close option.  To my surprise an error surfaced stating questions with a bounty cannot be closed.  I wound up skipping it as I cannot vote the way I want to.

Since I cannot pick an action as the bounty disallows it, should we not exclude bounty questions from the queue?  This might be an edge case, but I do know that question that have had a bounty on them are not used for audits as the bounty could skew the votes on the question ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300560/should-i-be-concerned-about-featured-questions-inflating-votes#comment227630_300560)).

Comment: Related: [feature request to exclude bounties from audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278398/exclude-open-bounty-questions-in-review-audits)

Answer (score 16):

Since the question merits closure, but is bountied, you should be flagging it for moderator attention to explain the situation to them, as they're the only people that can remove the bounty and close the question.

The fact that this is a question that merits moderation action it's very much a *good thing* that it was in the queue, as that has drawn attention to this fact so that it can be resolved, ideally quickly, since a bounty is involved.  If anything such posts should be given priority in the queue so that they're seen more quickly.

The only alternative that I could see is to automatically direct all VLQ flags on bounties questions directly to mods, rather than going through the triage queue.  One would need to have some stats on whether there are a lot of improper VLQ flags on bountied posts that the queue could properly dispute, or if there are a small enough number that the mods can just handle all of them.

Comment: I wonder why adrian008 sponsored a bounty there though... (his only involvement there being [this possible-dupe-comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882187/iso-c-forbids-declaration-of-multiset-with-no-type#comment51732744_31882187)).

Comment: @Deduplicator Presumably he has a similar problem?

Comment: If this is the case then maybe there ought to be an indication with the error to do this *"A question with a bounty cannot be flagged for closure this way. If you are **certain** this question should be closed, flag it for a moderator with a custom reason and they will review it."*