# Are very broad questions seeking ideas allowed on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155182/making-android-keyboard-resilient-against-keylogger-attacks) a good question here on Stack Overflow?

The question is quite interesting and the topic is important, but the question is not asking anything clear and focussed about programming. Instead the question asks for general ideas on a how to write some software. Someone appears to have received a +500 bonus.

Additionally, this question was placed in the triage review queue where the audit failure message shown to me included *"This question is clear and answerable. While there may be minor flaws, it Looks OK."*

Comment: The OP [bountied the question themselves](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32155182/revisions), it's way too broad to be on-topic.

Comment: Related: feature request to [Exclude open-bounty questions in review audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278398/exclude-open-bounty-questions-in-review-audits)